# How can I loop on a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to Insert all Rows values of DataGrid so I want to looping of DataGrid rows and 
insert cells values, In a window form I was using this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    sale.InsertPerchBill(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), comboBox1.Text) // Insert function
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how I will be able to looping of DataGrid because the code does not work in WPF.

How can I loop DataGrid and take rows values?

Comment: Is the data to be inserted into the rows held in a class? Do you have a List of all the row data?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring the data inserted into rows in datagrid if i have three rows i want to inserted at once

Comment: Seems that you make a confusion between Wpf and window form, if you want to add items to data

Comment: Seems that you have a confusion between wpf and winform why you dont add items to your datagrid  using binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the items in a datagrid. If you have the grid bound to a class you can just type cast it.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Items.Count; i++)
      (
       YourClass foo = (YourClass)dataGridView.Items[i];
       //do what you need to with that row (item)
      }
```

Try making a class to represent your rows, I will call my class "Person" in hopes to make it more understandable.

```
 public class Person
     {
      //make all appropriate cells into properties of class
      int age;
      int phoneNum;
      string name;
      }
```

Then create a list (call it List people) and insert all of the row objects to it.

```
 List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
   Person tempPerson = new Person(){age=5, phoneNum=5555555555};
   people.Add(tempPerson);
  }
```

Once the list is populated, just set the item source:

```
   dataGridView1.ItemsSource = people;
```

You can set the data grid to create column headers automatically based on the property name. In this case the column headers would be 'age', 'phoneNum', and "name";

Comment: how i catch to cell values here? and which class must i have?

Comment: does this answer make any sense? Should I explain populating the rowList?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using binding in WPF.
Lets say you have viewModel and you have property which  maybe collection or List.
You should bind this property to your DataGrid ItemSource in view and you can enumerate this collection as we do this in c# coding.